# Release retained property pointing at self.view

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, retain, viewdidunload

In an instance of an `UIViewController` with ARC best practice would be to "release" any retained subviews of the main view (e.g. `self.myOutlet = nil`) in `- viewDidUnload`, and my guess is `self.view = nil` isn't strictly necessary at this point.

What to do if an additional `retain`ed property is defined and assigned as...

> self.anotherProperty = self.view;

or

> _anotherProperty = self.view; // assuming "_anotherProperty" is the ivar

... is `self.anotherProperty = nil` necessary then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in `viewDidUnload` (I'm assuming we are talking about when running on pre-iOS 6, as views are no longer unloaded in iOS 6, and thus `viewDidUnload` is no longer called) is "necessary"; it's only an optional opportunity to unload stuff.

But if you wanted to unload stuff properly following the convention for `viewDidUnload`, should you nil your property? Yes. 1) If not, your property will still retain the view object, preventing it from being deallocated, which is the point of unloading the view. 2) The view has been unloaded, which means `self.view` is set to nil, and will be set to a newly loaded view when we decide to load the view. If you want your property to always point to `self.view`, then you need to follow suit and set it to nil on unload and set it to the loaded view in `viewDidLoad`.